# Why is the error "Script error: No such module "en-headword"" even if this module is already imported in my MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have downloaded the xml containing the entry `tease out` along with all its templates and modules from the link https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&pages=tease_out&templates.

Clearly, this xml contains module `en-headword`.

[image]

Then I import this xml with

```
php C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.35.2-0\apps\mediawiki\htdocs\maintenance\importDump.php C:/Users/Akira/Desktop/tease_out.xml

php C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.35.2-0\apps\mediawiki\htdocs\maintenance\rebuildrecentchanges.php

php C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.35.2-0\apps\mediawiki\htdocs\maintenance\initSiteStats.php
```

Then it shows on my cmd that

```
C:\Users\Akira>php C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.35.2-0\apps\mediawiki\htdocs\maintenance\importDump.php C:/Users/Akira/Desktop/tease_out.xml
Done!
You might want to run rebuildrecentchanges.php to regenerate RecentChanges,
and initSiteStats.php to update page and revision counts

C:\Users\Akira>php C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.35.2-0\apps\mediawiki\htdocs\maintenance\rebuildrecentchanges.php
Rebuilding $wgRCMaxAge=7776000 seconds (90 days)
Clearing recentchanges table for time range...
Loading from page and revision tables...
Inserting from page and revision tables...
Updating links and size differences...
Loading from user and logging tables...
Flagging bot account edits...
Flagging auto-patrolled edits...
Removing duplicate revision and logging entries...
Deleting feed timestamps.
Done.

C:\Users\Akira>php C:\Bitnami\mediawiki-1.35.2-0\apps\mediawiki\htdocs\maintenance\initSiteStats.php
Refresh Site Statistics

Counting total edits...52
Counting number of articles...1
Counting total pages...45
Counting number of users...2
Counting number of images...0

To update the site statistics table, run the script with the --update option.

Done.
```

Could you please explain why the content is not rendered properly?

[image]

Comment: You might want to check Module:en-headword to confirm if the module is actually imported. Also, make sure you have ParserFunctions installed for {{#if:}}s to work properly.

Comment: I also notice that you have not set $wgCapitalLinks to false, which is the setting on Wiktionaries, as Wiktionary entries are completely case-sensitive. Not setting $wgCapitalLinks to false would case the first letter of page titles to be capitalised, which might complicate things.

Comment: @user15517071 It works like a charm https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWlsx.png. The only remain problem is the error `Lua error in Module:headword at line 90: bad argument #1 to 'inNamespace' (unrecognized namespace name 'Appendix').`.  I've searched Google but could not find any related information. Could you please elaborate on this issue?

Comment: You need to set extra namespaces. See [the documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces) for more info. In particular, you need to add a namespace named Appendix and a corresponding talk namespace.